# Swapping first and last name in C

Tags: c

My question is to understand **why** this happens.

My goal is to pass a first name 'Joe' and last name 'Bloggs' into the swap function I created and have it switch them around. (So First name will now contain Bloggs vice versa)

I've created a swap function that takes pointers to the first and last name as arguments. The function appears to work because using the print statement I can see the values of the two strings has changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char * first, char * last) {
    char * temp;
    temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;
    printf("at end of swap func the first name is: %s\n", first);
    printf("at end of swap func the last name is: %s\n", last);
}
```

Now here appears to be the problem, after the swap function is called, I print the first and last name again, but they aren't displaying the results of the swap function.

```
int main() {
    char * first = "Joe";
    char * last = "Bloggs";
    printf("The original format: %s %s\n", first, last);
    swap(first, last);
    printf("The new format: %s %s", first, last);//new format was supposed to be Bloggs Joe
}
```

I have searched SO but the questions I've found are not specific to mine.  As I said earlier, I'd really like to know why this happens. I have very little knowledge of C so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The `first` and `last` are passed by value and the result of their modification is not leaving the function.

Comment: The pointer variables are passed by value, so they retain their original values after the function returns.

Comment: The call in `main` should be `swap(&first, &last)`. The `swap` function then needs to be modified accordingly.

Comment: You can't change the contents either since the pointers are pointing to constant strings.

Comment: @stark The OP doesn't even attempt that.

Comment: This is a really well-written high-quality question, especially considering that you're new to the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, all parameters are pass by value.  That means that `first` and `last` in the function are distinct from `first` and `last` in `main`.  Changes to a local variable are not reflected in the caller.

You need to pass the **address** of the variables you want to change.  Then in the function, you dereference the given pointers to change what they point to.

So change your function as follows:

```
void swap(char ** first, char ** last) {
  char * temp;
  temp = *first;
  *first = *last;
  *last = temp;
  printf("at end of swap func the first name is: %s\n", *first);
  printf("at end of swap func the last name is: %s\n", *last);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
swap(&first, &last);
```

Note that what's actually being swapped are the *pointer values*, not what the pointers actually point to.  You could swap the characters between the two strings, but the strings in question are **string literals** which cannot be modified.

If you had `char` arrays that contained strings, then you could swap the characters.  In fact, you would have to do it that way because arrays are not the same as pointers.

Here's a full example of how you would do a full string swap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// assumes that each array is big enough to hold the contents of the other
void swap(char *first, char *last) {
  int len1 = strlen(first);
  int len2 = strlen(last);
  int maxlen = (len1 > len2) ? len1 : len2;
  char temp[maxlen+1];
  strcpy(temp, first);
  strcpy(first, last);
  strcpy(last, temp); 
  printf("at end of swap func the first name is: %s\n", first);
  printf("at end of swap func the last name is: %s\n", last);
}

int main() {
  char first[10] = "Joe";
  char last[10] = "Bloggs";
  printf("The original format: %s %s\n", first, last);
  swap(first, last);
  printf("The new format: %s %s", first, last);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but might be improved with a mention of the fact that only the pointers are being swapped - not the actual characters in memory; that string literals have read-only static storage and cannot be modified; and maybe links to more information on strings in C. I.e. the OP should be aware that there is more to strings in C than meets the eye.

Comment: @dbush the second part of your answer highlighted and fixed the problem. A lack of understanding between string literals and character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping variables is idiomatically done inline with a temporary:

```
char *temp;
temp = first;
first = last;
last = first;
```

This doesn't translate well into a C function call, which uses pass by value. This means the function receives a copy of the value as its parameters. You could write a macro instead, but a general purpose macro has to take care of issues like arguments being expressions, and avoid name collisions of its own internal variables from the parameters being passed in.

```
#define swap(A, B) do {            \
    char **swap_A__ = &(A);        \
    char **swap_B__ = &(B);        \
    char *swap_temp__ = *swap_A__; \
    *swap_A__ = *swap_B__;         \
    *swap_B__ = swap_temp__;       \
} while (0)
```

This saves you from writing a function, but the implementation loses the simplicity of the idiomatic approach.

While the function call would be preferred, it loses the appearance of a pass by reference interface. If you were able to implement a generic swapping function:

```
void swap_generic(void *a, void *b, size_t sz);
```

Then, you could wrap your swap macro to call the generic function, and give you the ability to simulate a "call by reference" interface, but passing the appropriate arguments to the generic function:

```
#define swap(A, B) do {                                    \
    _Static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B), "unswappable"); \
    _Static_assert(sizeof(&(A) - &(B)), "type check");     \
    swap_generic(&(A), &(B), sizeof(A));                   \
} while (0)
```

Implementing the generic swapping function could be done as follows:

```
void swap_generic (void *a, void *b, size_t sz) {
    char *aa = a;
    char *bb = b;
    while (sz--) {
        char temp = *aa;
        *aa++ = *bb;
        *bb++ = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char ** first, char ** last) {
  char * temp;
  temp = *first;
  *first = *last;
  *last = temp;
  printf("at end of swap func the first name is: %s\n", *first);
  printf("at end of swap func the last name is: %s\n", *last);
}

int main() {
  char * first = "Joe";
  char * last = "Bloggs";
  printf("The original format: %s %s\n", first, last);
  swap(&first, &last);
  printf("The new format: %s %s", first, last);//new format was supposed to be Bloggs Joe
}
```

Pass the address of parameters if you want to change it, not the values.

Comment: This is not passing by reference